# Code runner for Mac Code Completion

Tags: macos, ide

My friend told me that code runner can auto complete your variables, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to add this setting. How can I make the application remember my variables and suggest them in the code completion tab.

Comment: [have you emailed the developer?](http://krillapps.com/support/coderunner/)

Answer (score 1):

I use Coderunner mainly for Python development, coupled with virtualenvwrapper this is a *great* development suite.

I am guessing that your friend was speaking of Preferences->General->"Suggest completion while typing".  Unfortunately, in Python, it only shows the built in functions.  All of my local variables / custom modules do not show up in the completions.  I cannot speak on for all languages, but I would assume they would follow suit.

This feature would be very useful, so I look forward to finding a solution as well.